# How do you change the user the executes tests (MSTest)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I am creating a library to work with windows services (poll their status, start them, check their cpu usage, etc). I am writing unit tests for this library. I need to change the user that is used by the test runs so that they have permision to perform some actions (start a service).

How can I change the identity the tests run under?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t a test specific solution to this. The short answer is: Impersonate the user you need using LogonUser(). The long answer is much longer, because LogonUser() is a Win32 call.

Take a look at this [blog that’s trying to solve your problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimmytr/archive/2007/04/14/writing-test-code-with-impersonation.aspx).

I liked this [codeproject implementation for calling LogonUser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx) better. There's actually many codeproject examples of LogonUser() if you search around a little.